# what is the url I use to access Annotated URL

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, annotations

I have this class

```
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/draw")
public class DrawEndpoint{...}
```

and im trying to access it from js

```
var url = "wss://localhost:7101/websocket-draw";
websocket = new WebSocket(url);
```

but I keep getting a ERR_TIMED_OUT.

interestingly I have another web app that does the same but works.
both have the same code above.
But are different projects / examples.

So what else affects what the URL is that the websocket has to goto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant believe nobody knows this.

it seems to me that it should be
wss://localhost:7101/websocket-draw/draw

and most of my problem was that I was going through a proxy and not setting it up correctly.